# I am using Kafka streaming in azure databricks using foreachbatch but checkpoint is not updating

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

Why checkpoint is not updating?

```
df2.writeStream \

    .foreachBatch(lambda batch_df, batch_id: processBatch(batch_df, batch_id)) \
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds') \
    .start()

# Reading file and converting to a DataFrame object
# For loop is used to iterate each row in the DataFrame

def processBatch(batch_df, batch_id):

    for row in batch_df.collect():

        jsonMessage = unstringer(row["text"])

        # Passing JSON format data to validate_row function to validate the columns
        validation_error, jMessage = validate_row(jsonMessage)

        # If there are no errors, JSON format data is inserted into the rejected records table
        if not validation_error:

            spark.sql("INSERT INTO claim.bronze_clc_message_error_dev VALUES (current timestamp (), ?)", (json.dumps(jMessage),))

        else:

            spark.sql("INSERT INTO claim.bronze_claims_life_cycle_dev VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (jMessage.get('claimId', ''), jMessage.get('messageCreatedTs', ''), json.dumps(jMessage)
))
```

Comment: This is very inefficient code, that most probably won't work well in production...